# Change order of string content

Tags: php

I have this data

```
$s = '{ "date": "2015-07-30","value": 66568 },{ "date": "2015-07-29","value": 66598 },{ "date": "2015-07-28","value": 66680 },{ "date": "2015-07-27","value": 66774 }';
```

Im graphing the data and basically i need the graph to show the earliest date first, this can be accomplished if i simply flip the data. I tried using:

```
implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(',', $s)))
```

and that didnt work.

The data comes from the db and is appended to

```
if($test!=1) {
    $testString = $testString.',{ "date": "'.date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date)).'","value": '.$res[$row]['followed_by'].' }';  
} else {
    $testString = $testString.'{ "date": "'.date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date)).'","value": '.$res[$row]['followed_by'].' }';  
}
```

The data is added to the graph with `"dataProvider": [ <?php echo $testString; ?> ]`

Comment: How do you get this string? Looks like a broken JSON string

Comment: @Dagon First the json needs to be valid :)

Comment: @Rizier123 fair point.

Comment: Why don't you just create a simple array?

Comment: " data comes from the db" `ORDER by date_field` in the query

Comment: @dragon i am doesnt work

Comment: lets fix that rather than ignore the obvious best approach - so whats the querry exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this code:

```
$s = '{ "date": "2015-07-30","value": 66568 },{ "date": "2015-07-29","value": 66598 },{ "date": "2015-07-28","value": 66680 },{ "date": "2015-07-27","value": 66774 }';

function reverse_str($str) {
  $decoded = json_decode(sprintf('[%s]', $str), true);
  $reversed = array_reverse($decoded);
  return trim(json_encode($reversed), '[,]');  
}

Usage:
$newStr = reverse_str($s);
```

Comment: this worked ith this data but how can i implement this? so it will add the comma like above?

Comment: @user2002220 boggles the mind that you think this is a better approach than just fixing the query, but oooook.

Comment: @user2002220 I updated an answer a bit, just make it look pretty. But I'm glad it worked!

Comment: @dragon the query is used multiple times in the file if i get the order changed by date then it my change the order of a table using the query

Comment: that's really a bad excuse, its less code, faster, safer and better codeine practice to change the sort order at the query